# Remove index.php from admin url on live server?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin

I  am trying to resolve this problem form 2 day ago but i cant success to resolved it

I  given all details of this problem

we have magento installed on root directory i.e public_html on live server

> .htaccess file of server is something like this,

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php5 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php52 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml

RewriteEngine on


Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # we skip all files in /web
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/zimode/
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we rewrite all other files with .something to /web
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zimode/$1 [L]

  # !!! UNTESTED !!! ##################################
  # we check if the .html version is in /web (caching)
  #RewriteRule ^$ /zimode/index.html [QSA]
  #RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /zimode/$1.html [QSA]
  #####################################################

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zimode/[QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

What i had already try to resolve it as,

> i had enabled  `mod_rewrite`  using admin panel.
>   
> try to install admin url module which remove index.php from admin url.

Note:

`xyz.com/admin/`

when i hit above url i see admin login panel i am login successful but got

page not found

404 error occurred....

and now url changed something like  `xyz.com/index.php/admin/......`

when i remove that index.php  from url it works

So any one have any idea? How to resolve it.

Waiting for your answer...  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of you have to enable mod_rewrite apache server.

   How enable mod_rewrite for Apache?
2. then Go to Admin -> System-> Configuration
3. Under configuration -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization settings Use Web Server Rewrites->select Yes
4. click Save Config Button.
5. Then Go to Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP module is called 'mod_rewrite', not 'mod_rewrite**s**'. Maybe that is the issue? Also, place a PHP file with contents `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on your server and run it to see whether mod_rewrite is correctly loaded.

Comment: i am agree with your correction but i am not edited any php.ini. In magento there is way to enable servers rewrite form magento admin panel which remove index.php from url and i.e
>  system-configuration-web-search engines optimization-Use Web Server Rewrites.

I am saying above rewites enble. not you think like as.....

Answer (score 0):

Another method of doing this does involve modifying a core Magento file (which is a big no, no for upgrading purposes) but works all the same: http://www.code007.ro/magento-how-to-remove-index-php-from-admin-url/

Obviously test within a test environment and create a copy of the modified file in the local directory rather than editing the core file itself as outlined in the post.